# Jquery Validate gives error if file not uploaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate for my form. All validation rules are working quite well but I have some issues with file validation.

I have 3 file inputs, 2 of which are required and 1 is not. If I upload all 3 files then the rules work fine. However if I did not upload a file in the 3rd input (nic) then it gives me a filesize error and no validation runs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, arg) {
      if (element.files[0].size <= arg) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    $("#Cnd_reg_form").validate({
      rules: {
        passport: {
          required: true,
          extension: "docx|jpeg|png|doc|pdf",
          filesize: 4000000
        },
        license: {
          required: true,
          extension: "docx|jpeg|png|doc|pdf",
          filesize: 2000000
        },
        nic: {
          required: false,
          extension: "docx|jpeg|png|doc|pdf",
          filesize: 2000000
        }
      },
      messages: {
        passport: {
          required: "Please upload your passport",
          extension: "Please upload file with extension doc,pdf,jpeg,png",
          filesize: "Please select file under 4MB"
        },
        license: {
          required: "Please upload your license",
          extension: "Please upload file with extension doc,pdf,jpeg,png",
          filesize: "Please select file under 2MB"
        },
        nic: {
          extension: "Please upload file with extension doc,pdf,jpeg,png",
          filesize: "Please select file under 2MB"
        }
      },
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent());
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: The `addMethod()` call is missing a closing `)`, although I assume that's just a typo in the question as the code wouldn't work at all in this state.

Comment: Check the possibility if the "filesize" validation is getting fired which i doubt is getting fired. Give a null check in addMethod(). File won't be getting element.files[0] code. Hence might be returning false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the filesize check always runs, regardless of whether or not the field is required. Therefore if no file is provided in the field the validation rejects the submission.

To fix this simply check if the file is optional before checking the size:

```js
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, arg) {
  if (this.optional(element))
    return;

  if (element.files[0].size <= arg) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

This can be further simplified to:

```js
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, arg) {
  return this.optional(element) || element.files[0].size <= arg;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help can you also please tell me  how to avoid extension check if file not uploaded in 3rd input (nic)

Comment: That validator is already configured to work with optional inputs. If you check the [source file on line 686](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.js) you can see it also performs the `this.optional()` check

Comment: Also note that the `extension` rule has now been superceded by [`accept`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/)

Comment: Yes you are right. This worked for me. Thanks for your help